# java.io.IOException while starting jpenable on remote server

Tags: java, exception, ubuntu, jprofiler

Using JProfiler for a first time today.

I've started jpenable on my remote ubuntu server, but after I've inserted port java exception appeared:

```
Please enter a profiling port
[31758]
8086
java.io.IOException: Premature EOF
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.readInt(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:226)
    at sun.tools.attach.LinuxVirtualMachine.execute(LinuxVirtualMachine.java:193)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentLibrary(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:40)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.loadAgentPath(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:70)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.AgentLoader.a(ejt:26)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.b(ejt:291)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:278)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.attach.c.a(ejt:248)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.a(ejt:118)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.g(ejt:81)
    at com.jprofiler.frontend.EnableApplication.main(ejt:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source)
```

What's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: It's a failure in the attach API of the JVM. Are you running jpenable as the same user as the JVM that you want to profile? If not, try doing that.

Comment: @IngoKegel, thank you, but I'm running it both with the same user.